# display inline block without float

Tags: html, css

I have these 3 div's. they are set to display inline-block in a wrapper with a width of 1000px. each div is 330px. I have some issues getting them to line up but i dont want to use float left. 
How do i display them inline block?

[image of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whjID.png)

Comment: `vertical-align: top`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add **[`vertical-align`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)** to your elements. The `value` depends on how you want the elements to align, but you're probably looking for `vertical-align: top`.

Without `vertical-align`:

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  width: 330px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>ASDASD</div>
<div>ASD</div>
<div></div>
```

With `vertical-align`:

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  width: 330px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>ASDASD</div>
<div>ASD</div>
<div></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a fiddle with your code, otherwise this seems to work

```
<div style="width:1000px;background:#aaa">
  <div style="width:330px;display:inline-block;background:#f00">
    a
  </div>
  <div style="width:330px;display:inline-block;background:#0f0">
    b
  </div>
  <div style="width:330px;display:inline-block;background:#00f">
    c
  </div>
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/ptornhult/xoqLgtq1/

Answer (score 0):

they should automatically line up if they have space.  There is something else pushing it down, see below  as long as you have width they should auto line up.

```
.wrapper {
 width: 1060px;
 border: 10px solid green; 
}
.inline {
 border: 10px solid red;
 height: 500px;
 width: 330px; 
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

borders have a impact on size as well so you need to have the wrapper fit borders as well (hence why my wrapper is slightly larger).

https://codepen.io/Zuriel/pen/VMmdbw

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle trying to replicate your issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/4pvebp05/

It may be that you have not set your container to be `display: block`?

In that case, try `vertical-align: middle`

Answer (score -1):

We can do two different ways

Display `inline-block`.

```
<div class="inline">
  <div>
    First
  </div>
  <div>
    Second
  </div>
  <div>
    Third
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inline{
  width:1000px;
}
.inline div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:330px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/md25je2g/

Display `flex` divide three equal column

```
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    First
  </div>
  <div>
    Second
  </div>
  <div>
    Third
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex{
  display:flex;
  width:1000px;
}
.flex div{
  flex:1;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mL3eqvoe/